# Отозвать права от / у пользователя

Tags: выбор-слов

Как правильно:

Отозвать права администратора **у** или **от** (или др.?) пользователя такого-то.

Comment: Добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что "у". Чем отозвать лучше "отнять"? "От меня отнять" или "у меня отнять"? Если "я" - не математическая величина и "у меня".

А откуда вообще "от" появилось, по какой парадигме или аналогии?

UPD: 
Как такое может прийти в голову без аналогии, не понимаю.
Но думаю, что нашел общий принцип.

"От" отнимают, отбирают, отбивают и т.д. только то, что не принадлежит и не относится никаким образом тому, у кого/чего отбирают, а только рядом находится, когда важно само движение, а не *лишение* чего-чего либо. 
В остальных случаях - только "У".

Comment: Без парадигм и аналогии появилось, просто интуитивно.

Answer (score 0):

**Сравним глаголы отозвать и отнять.**

ОТНЯТЬ, 1. что. **Взять у кого-л**. силой, вопреки его желанию; отобрать, завладеть чем-л., присвоить себе. О. игрушку у ребёнка. О. имущество у наследников. Незаконно о. добычу у охотников. 2. что. Лишить чего-л.  О. жизнь у кого-л. (убить, погубить). 4. кого-что. Отдалить, **отстранить от чего-л**., отвести в сторону, убрать. О. лестницу от стены. О. руку от огня. О. платок от глаз.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

ОТ/У - **лишить** предмета того, что он имел (пользователь - права, чайник - носик), а ОТ/ОТ - **отстранить, удалить** от  предмета.

Далее рассмотрим **семантику** конкретного глагола отнять: что-то отнять (отобрать, отозвать) можно у одушевленных предметов (речь идет о лишении их права собственности на предмет). Для этих глаголов используется только вариант ОТ/У, а вариант ОТ/ОТ, согласно словарю, - это удаление, отстранение (от неодушевленного предмета). Например: отнять ребенка у матери, отнять ребенка от груди.

Поэтому правильно: **отозвать права у пользователя**.

Comment: Интересное наблюдение. Но недостоверное.  А почему не "отбить"? Отбить носик у чайника. Не от чайка же?

Comment: Я думаю, что Вас смутило то, что у одушевленных предметов в этих примерах отнимаю как правило то, что им принадлежит, к ним относится. А у неодушевленных - только то, что *рядом* с ними. А вот права вполне можно отнять у грамматически неодушевленной  *группы* пользователей.

Comment: Вы говорите: "Сравним глаголы отозвать и отнять.". Но в итоге рассуждаете о глаголе "отнять", а глагол "отозвать" не разбирается. Так что я не вижу, где тут сравнение двух глаголов.

Comment: Отозвать - что. Офиц. Потребовать возвращения назад (в прежнее положение, на своё прежнее место. Фактически отозвать права - это ОТНЯТЬ у лица предоставленные ему  ранее права".